# azurerm_app_service application settings

Tags: azure, terraform

Looking to find a way to pull my Application Settings from the TF file defining my Azure Application Service such that they are more readable and can be handed over to a developer to supply before deployment.   I don't see a handy way to do that with Terraform, though I have found some tricks to import them using PowerShell post-deployment.

Is there a clear way to do this using Terraform without the added Powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to import all resources together, hashicorp is still working on this feature. There is an open source which can do some jobs partly: https://github.com/dtan4/terraforming

Secondly, you can write the code and manually import the resource if it supports by `terraform import` command.

#### Not all resources is supported by import command

For example, you mentioned the resource [azurerm_app_service](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service.html) which has `import` feature.

Import

App Services can be imported using the resource id, e.g.

```
terraform import azurerm_app_service.instance1 /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/mygroup1/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/instance1
```